# Integral relations in Fricke and Klein

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions, translation-request

Can someone please explain how Fricke and Klein obtain the integral relationa stated at the top of p. 34 in this [book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=2ZQLAAAAYAAJ)? The entire book can be previewed on Google Books. It is an old book and I do not speak German. Also, is there a modern account of this anywhere in the modern literature?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Page 34 is not on google books. If you post the relation, or at least an image, then perhaps this question will be answered faster, since many people may not have the german book in question.

Comment: @Andy You can preview the entire book.

Comment: Your right. My computer glitched, and it was not working.

Comment: I am a German native speaker and I can translate passages of the book if you wish. However, I cannot see any integrals on p. 34...

Comment: @sranthrop I would really appreciate your help. There are three relations at the top of p. 34. The derivation starts at the bottom of p. 33 right after (3).

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see a line labeled with (3) on p. 33. I'm using https://archive.org/stream/vorlesungenberd04kleigoog#page/n51/mode/2up, maybe you can tell me where the passage you are talking about is in there.

Comment: @sranthrop You are using vol. 2. As far as I know vol. 1 is not on archive.org. Use the link to vol. 1 in my question. You should be able to preview the entire book.

Comment: A quick and dirty way to get an answer: type the text into Google translate.

Comment: @Potato Try it and see what happens.

Comment: @glebovg I get a reasonable translation of the parts I tried. Presumably a German-English math dictionary would help with the trouble spots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the Weierstrass Normal form, let's try to understand the elliptic integral

$$ \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{4y^3 - g_2 y - g_3}} $$

In order to reduce the number of parameters, Fricke and Klein do a change of variables $y = \frac{g_2}{g_3}z$.  The elliptic curve has two basic periods

$$ \Omega = \int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{4z^3 + g(z+1)}} 
\text{ and }
-H = \int \frac{z\,dz}{\sqrt{4z^3 + g(z+1)}} 
$$
This new parameter $g$ is basically the [$J$-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant) in disguise.  $\frac{27 J}{1-J} = g $.  Let's just call the denominator $R = \sqrt{\dots}$.

---

What happens if we change $g$?  Let's differentiate under the integral sign:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d\Omega}{dg} &=&  - &\int \frac{dz}{2R^3} & - &\int \frac{z \, dz}{2R^3}\\
\frac{dH}{dg}      &=&  & \int \frac{z \, dz}{2R^3} &+& \int \frac{z^2 \, dz}{2R^3}
\end{eqnarray}

These are called the [Picard-Fuchs equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Fuchs_equation).  In modern language, this is an instance of the [Gauss-Manin connection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525575/reference-for-gauss-manin-connection).

The integral of any derivative along a closed path on the elliptic curve is going to be zero.

$$ \int d\left(\frac{z^a}{R}\right) = 
\int \frac{a z^{a-1}}{R} - \int \frac{z^a(12 z^2 + g)}{2R^3}
 = 0  \tag{$\ast$}$$

The first step says the derivative and integral are inverse operations -  the fundamental theorem of calculus. For a closed path the two endpoints are the same so the integral is zero. For the second step use the quotient rule for derivatives and the definition of R as the denominator.

The first relation comes from setting $a = 0$ without any changes.  The second and third relations start from setting $a = 1,2$ with some extra manipulation.

**EDIT** Yeah, they fall out of $R^2 = 4z^3 + g(z+1)$ and the definition of the periods $\Omega, H$.

---

Fricke and Klein solve for the periods and ultimately find the differential equation the period $\Omega$ satisfies in terms of the elliptic curve invariant $J$:

$$ \frac{d^2 \Omega}{dJ^2}  +
 \frac{1}{J} \cdot  \frac{d \Omega}{dJ} + \frac{\frac{31}{144}J- \frac{1}{36}}{J^2(J-1)^2}\Omega = 0$$

---

### When is $\oint \neq 0$ ?

The fundamental theorem of calculus says: $\int_a^b F'(x) \, dx = F(b) - F(a)$  so we integrate along a closed path, $a = b$ so the integral should be $F(b) - F(a) = 0$.  Yet,

$$ \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i \neq 0 $$

What goes wrong is that $\frac{1}{z}$ is not holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, it is only holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$.  By removing the one point we no longer have a plane, but a punctured plane.  The circle $|z| = 1$ moves around this puncture and therefore integrating has a residue.

Another important issue is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$.  The problem here is as we move around the unit circle from $1$ back to itself, the square roots go to $-1$.

$$ \sqrt{1} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{1}} \to \sqrt{i} = \mathbf{\tfrac{\color{blue}{1+i}}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{2}}}} \to \sqrt{-1} = \mathbf{\color{blue}{i}}\to \sqrt{-i} = \mathbf{\tfrac{\color{blue}{1-i}}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{2}}}} \to \sqrt{1} = -\mathbf{\color{green}{1}}$$

Basically every number has two square roots except for $0$, therefore the riemann surface $\{ (z, \pm \sqrt{z}): z \in \mathbb{C} \}$ has branching at $0$.

---

Using the identity $(\ast)$ with $a=1$ we can solve the **2nd** identity.

\begin{eqnarray} \frac{1}{2}\Omega = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dz}{R} 
= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{R^2 }{R^3 } dz 
&=&  \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{4z^3 + g(z+1) }{R^3 } dz \\
&=&  \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{4z^3 + g(z+1) + (-4z^3 + g(z+2))}{R^3 } dz \\
&=& 2g \int \frac{ z \, dz}{2R^3 }   + 3g \int \frac{ dz}{2R^3 }  \end{eqnarray}

---

Using the identity $(\ast)$ with $a=2$ we can solve the **3rd** identity.

\begin{eqnarray} \tfrac{1}{2}H = -\tfrac{1}{2}\int \frac{z}{R} \, dz
= -\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{z R^2}{R^3} \, dz
&=& - \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{z(4z^3 + g(z+1)) }{R^3 } dz \\
&=&  -\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{ -g(3z^2 + 4z) + g(z+1)z }{R^3 } dz \\
&=& 2g \int \frac{ z^2 \,dz }{2R^3 } 
+ 3g\int \frac{ z \,dz}{2R^3 }  \end{eqnarray}

Comment: Do you know why the integral of any derivative along a closed path on the elliptic curve is going to be zero?

Comment: @glebovg That's just the fundamental theorem of calculus, basically. (Stoke's theorem implies the integral of an exact form over a closed path is zero.)

Comment: I still do not understand how to obtain the last two relations. They do not simply follow from the definitions of $\Omega$ and $H$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @glebovg OK I included details about those two equations.  Let me know if you need more.

Comment: @johnmangual Thanks. We just add zero (of course).

Comment: @johnmangual Perhaps you could add more details about $(\ast)$ for 100 rep? For the sake of completeness?

Comment: @glebovg I enjoyed this exercise since Fricke Klein is such an important read. It is in German fortunately we were able to decipher this passage and it was basically just some advanced calculus.

Comment: @johnmangual I agree. Thanks.

Comment: @glebovg i added more details... why didn't you give me the 100?

Comment: @johnmangual I missed the deadline. I thought it would be rewarded automatically since your answer is the only one. Strange. This needs to be fixed.

Comment: @glebovg I think they want to give you the option of not awarding any bounty at all.  In the case nobody answers the way you wanted.